# How to populate dropdown automatically on page load in angular 5?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I want to know can we autopopulate the dropdown on page load in angular. If yes then how?
Thank you.

Comment: show what you tried & update your question according to - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> You need to understand **[component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)** first. In your case, you need a hook ***`OnInit`*** which will be called on component load.

So, you'll need to implement `OnInit` hook & write its method as shown in the following ***sample code*** -

```
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
    public dataArray = [];
    public selectedItem: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataArray = [
            { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
            { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
            { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
        ];
    }

    onDropDownChange() {
        alert(this.selectedItem);
    }
}
```

Then, use it in your HTML script as follows -

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="onDropDownChange()">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of dataArray" [ngValue]="item?.id">{{item?.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can totally do that.

just fetch the data used for your dopdown in this case `dropdownListCodes` on component load in `ngOnInit(){}` and in your html template:

```
<select id="inputSelectReason" class="form-control" formControlName="selectReason">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Your Reason</option>
    <option *ngFor="let code of dropdownListCodes?.codes" [value]="code.codeValue">{{code.codeDescTxt}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but can you be more descriptive.

Comment: @vikrantbute, please try something on your side, do not expect the code being handed out to you.